# How can I ignore the search field from jquery datatable bstatesave

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I want to save all the fields in `bstatesave` except for search

This is my code

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        {orderable: false, targets: -1}
    ],
    "bStateSave": true
});
```

I tried several ways but either search re-appears of jquery datatable doesn't work. I want it to work exactly like this, just don't the search in it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation you can use the following callback:

> [stateSaveParams( settings, data )](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveParams): allows modification of the parameters to be saved for the DataTables state saving

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false, targets: -1
    }],
    "bStateSave": true,
    "stateSaveParams": function (settings, data) {
        data.search.search = "";
    }
});
```